# Remove part from a string

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I am working on an iOS App using Swift 4. I am writing some data to a Firebase Database ("FB-DB"). When reading the data, the app generates the following:

```
let sharedDataReceivedWithBraces = "[\(each.1)]"
```

The respective console output is the following after `print(sharedDataReceivedWithBraces)`:

```
[{
id = "EEBEA75A-4DD0-4B30-84FB-1610A664276A";
key = "-Ku5VUHb5rbiy1ipFPL1";
code = 81358;
time = "14:06";
}]
```

I want to remove the braces (`{`, `}`) from this to further process the info, but I struggle a lot with this. Can you help me how to make my console's output look like this?

```
[
id = "EEBEA75A-4DD0-4B30-84FB-1610A664276A";
key = "-Ku5VUHb5rbiy1ipFPL1";
code = 81358;
time = "14:06";
]
```

Thank you very much for your great and patient help!

Cheers,

*Janninho*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String`'s `replacingWithOccurences` for this task.

```
let sharedDataWithoutBraces = "[\(each.1)]"
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "{", with: "")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "}", with: "")
```

Comment: Do you know how I can transform the output from above – before the "clean-up" – in an array?

Comment: What do you mean by "transforming"?